# How in the world do you remove an action in iAd producer?

Tags: macos

I am using iAd producer this afternoon to make iAds for some of my apps. I have googled around but I still cannot figure out how to remove an action that I have added to an action list. I have tried dragging the action out of the list, <kbd>control</kbd> clicking, <kbd>alt</kbd> clicking, <kbd>command</kbd> clicking, but I can't figure it out.

How do I delete the action?

Answer (score 1):

Go up to the **Edit Menu - Delete.**